# populate row with opposite value of the xth previous row, if condition is true

Tags: python, pandas

Following is the Dataframe I am starting from:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d= {'PX_LAST':[1,2,3,3,3,1,2,1,1,1,3,3],'ma':[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],'action':[0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,-1,0]}
df_zinc = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_zinc
```

#### Now, I need to add a column called 'buy_sell', which:

- when 'action'==1, populates with 1 if 'PX_LAST' >'ma', and with -1 if 'PX_LAST'<'ma'
- when 'action'==-1, populates with the opposite of the previous non-zero value that was populated

FYI: in my data, the row that needs to be filled with the opposite of the previous non-zero item is always at the same distance from the previous non-zero item (i.e., 2 in the current example). This should facilitate making the code.

#### the code that I made so far is the following. It seems right to me. Do you have any fixes to propose?

```
 while index < df_zinc.shape[0]:
    if df_zinc['action'][index] == 1:
        if df_zinc['PX_LAST'][index]<df_zinc['ma'][index]:
            df_zinc.loc[index,'buy_sell'] = -1
        else:
            df_zinc.loc[index,'buy_sell'] = 1
    elif df_zinc['action'][index] == -1:
            df_zinc['buy_sell'][index] = df_zinc['buy_sell'][index-3]*-1 
    index=index+1
df_zinc
```

#### the resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
    df_zinc['buy_sell'] = [0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,-1,0,0,1,0]

    df_zinc
```

Comment: Please include an example of the output you expect. It is hard for me to follow your logic here.

Comment: sure. here it is

Comment: shouldn't the line after `elif df_zinc['action'][index] == -1:` be `df_zinc.loc[index,'buy_sell'] = = df_zinc['PX_LAST'][index-3]*-1`? Otherwise you are overwriting PX_LAST instead of adding a new value to the 'buy_sell' column.

Comment: good spot! I changed it (check the new question), and now it seems to work actually. Do you spot any mistakes?

Comment: looping through pandas indexes like this is quite time costly. When possible you should avoid loops in a DataFrame at all or use provided functions such as apply. I've updated my answer in a way, I think, that now can fit your logic.

Comment: Your goal is to update the 'PX_LAST', 'buy_sell' or both?

Answer (score 1):

So, this would be my suggestion according to the example output (and assuming I understood the question properly:

```
def buy_sell(row):
   if row['action'] == 0:
      return 0
   if row['PX_LAST'] > row['ma']:
      return 1 * (-1 if row['action'] == 0 else 1)
   else:
      return -1 * (-1 if row['action'] == 0 else 1)
   return 0

df_zinc = df_zinc.assign(buy_sell=df_zinc.apply(buy_sell, axis=1))      
df_zinc
```

This should behave as expected by the rules. It does not take into account the possibility of 'PX_LAST' being equal to 'ma', returning 0 by default, as it was not clear what rule to follow in that scenario.

**EDIT**

Ok, after the new logic explained, I think this should do the trick:

```
def assign_buysell(df):
    last_nonzero = None
    def buy_sell(row):
        nonlocal last_nonzero
        if row['action'] == 0:
            return 0
        if row['action'] == 1:
            if row['PX_LAST'] < row['ma']:
                last_nonzero = -1
            elif row['PX_LAST'] > row['ma']:
                last_nonzero = 1
        elif row['action'] == -1:
            last_nonzero = last_nonzero * -1
        return last_nonzero
    return df.assign(buy_sell=df.apply(buy_sell, axis=1))
df_zinc = assign_buysell(df_zinc)
```

This solution is independent of how long ago the nonzero value was seen, it simply remembers the last nonzero value and pipes the opposite wen action is -1.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. This does not respect my logic unfortunately, though. I added my code on the question to clarify what I am trying to do. Do you know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), and use `np.nan` as a label for the rows that satisfy the third condition:

```
c1 = df_zinc.action.eq(1) & df_zinc.PX_LAST.gt(df_zinc.ma)
c2 = df_zinc.action.eq(1) & df_zinc.PX_LAST.lt(df_zinc.ma)
c3 = df_zinc.action.eq(-1)

df_zinc['buy_sell'] = np.select([c1,c2, c3], [1, -1, np.nan])
```

Now in order to fill `NaNs` with the value from `n` rows above (in this case `3`), you can [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with a shifted version of the dataframe:

```
df_zinc['buy_sell'] = df_zinc.buy_sell.fillna(df_zinc.buy_sell.shift(3)*-1)
```

**Output**

```
   PX_LAST  ma  action  buy_sell
0         1   2       0       0.0
1         2   2       0       0.0
2         3   2       1       1.0
3         3   2       0       0.0
4         3   2       0       0.0
5         1   2      -1      -1.0
6         2   2       0       0.0
7         1   2       1      -1.0
8         1   2       0       0.0
9         1   2       0       0.0
10        3   2      -1       1.0
11        3   2       0       0.0
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. This does not respect my logic unfortunately, though. I added my code on the question to clarify what I am trying to do. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: Updated @gianluca , that makes it much simpler :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for this, since you have multiple conditions:

```
conditions = [
    (df_zinc['action'] == 1) & (df_zinc['PX_LAST'] > df_zinc['ma']),
    (df_zinc['action'] == 1) & (df_zinc['PX_LAST'] < df_zinc['ma']),
    (df_zinc['action'] == -1) & (df_zinc['PX_LAST'] > df_zinc['ma']),
    (df_zinc['action'] == -1) & (df_zinc['PX_LAST'] < df_zinc['ma'])
]

choices = [1, -1, 1, -1]

df_zinc['buy_sell'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
```

**result**

```
print(df_zinc)
    PX_LAST  ma  action  buy_sell
0         1   2       0         0
1         2   2       0         0
2         3   2       1         1
3         3   2       0         0
4         3   2       0         0
5         1   2      -1        -1
6         2   2       0         0
7         1   2       1        -1
8         1   2       0         0
9         1   2       0         0
10        3   2      -1         1
11        3   2       0         0
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. This does not respect my logic unfortunately, though. I added my code on the question to clarify what I am trying to do. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: Could you clarify where it differs, since im getting the same output.

Comment: 'buy_sell' should be zero by default. That said, when it is in the same row where action=1, it should = 1 if PX_LAST>ma, and it should =-1 if PX_LAST<ma. When instead it is in the same row where action=-1, it should have the same value it had 3 rows before. In your code, the cases in which action=-1 do no link to buy_sell's previous value (the one 3 rows before). 

In my opinion, you can only execute this logic through a loop. Which is what I am trying to do (check my question - I edited it to include my current code).

Answer (score 0):

here my solution using the function shift() to trap the data of 3th up row:

```
df_zinc['buy_sell'] = 0
df_zinc.loc[(df_zinc['action'] == 1) & (df_zinc['PX_LAST'] < df_zinc['ma']), 'buy_sell'] = -1
df_zinc.loc[(df_zinc['action'] == 1) & (df_zinc['PX_LAST'] > df_zinc['ma']), 'buy_sell'] = 1
df_zinc.loc[df_zinc['action'] == -1, 'buy_sell'] = -df_zinc['buy_sell'].shift(3)
df_zinc['buy_sell'] = df_zinc['buy_sell'].astype(int)

print(df_zinc)
```

output:

```
    PX_LAST  ma  action  buy_sell 
0         1   2       0          0
1         2   2       0          0
2         3   2       1          1
3         3   2       0          0
4         3   2       0          0
5         1   2      -1         -1
6         2   2       0          0
7         1   2       1         -1
8         1   2       0          0
9         1   2       0          0
10        3   2      -1          1
11        3   2       0          0
```